# All combinations in array of arrays

Tags: arrays, algorithm

I am practicing a few coding questions and for some reasons I am not able to figure out a solution to below problem. I will appreciate if somebody could help me with algorithm or code to solve it.

Given a 2D array such as

```
 {{1}, {2,3}, {4,5,6}}
```

we need to generate all possible combinations such that exactly one element is picked from each array.

So for above input the result set should be

```
{{1,2,4}, {1,2,5}, {1,2,6}, {1,3,4}, {1,3,5}, {1,3,6}}
```

Another example:

```
Input = {{1,2,3}, {1,2}, {4,5}}
Output = {{1,1,4}, {1,1,5}, {1,2,4}, {1,2,5}, {2,1,4}, {2,1,5}, {2,2,4}, {2,2,5},{3,1,4}, {3,1,5}, {3,2,4}, {3,2,5}}
```

I tried implementing cartesian product approach but facing issues maintaining the modified list. This code is not working because I am updating the result list itself which is giving me final result as [[1,2,3],[1,2,3]] however it should be [[1,2],[1,3]]

```
public class CartisianProduct {
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[][] arr = { { 1 }, { 2, 3 } };
    cartisian(arr);
}

private static void cartisian(int[][] arr) {
    List<List<Integer>> result = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
    List<Integer> ll = new ArrayList<Integer>();
    for (int i : arr[0]) {
        ll.add(i);
    }
    result.add(ll);

    for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++) {
        result = cartisianHelper(result, arr[i]);
    }
    //System.out.println(result.get(0).toString() + "-" + result.get(1).toString());
}

private static List<List<Integer>> cartisianHelper(List<List<Integer>> result, int[] arr) {

    List<List<Integer>> rs = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
    List<List<Integer>> temp = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
    temp.addAll(result);
    for (int i = 0; i < result.size(); i++) {

        for (int j = 0; j < arr.length; j++) {
            List<Integer> ll = temp.get(i);
            ll.add(arr[j]);
            rs.add(ll);
        }
    }
    return rs;
}
}
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product

Comment: Thanks m69! That helped.

Comment: What's the question? What have you tried to solve it?

Comment: You can simply recurse to deeper levels and get those combinations. What have you tried?

Comment: @vivek_23 I posted the approach I am following.

Comment: When you say “a minimum of one element” do you mean “exactly one element”?

Comment: Yes @Ry- that's what I mean. My bad! I will correct the wording in my post.

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
class Solution{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        int[][] arr1 = {{1,2,3}, {1,2}, {4,5}};
        System.out.println(cartesianProduct(arr1,0,arr1.length).toString());
        int[][] arr2 = {{1},{2,3},{4,5,6}};
        System.out.println(cartesianProduct(arr2,0,arr2.length).toString());
        int[][] arr3 = {};
        System.out.println(cartesianProduct(arr3,0,arr3.length).toString());
        int[][] arr4 = {{1},{2}};
        System.out.println(cartesianProduct(arr4,0,arr4.length).toString());
        int[][] arr5 = {{99,101},{2000}};
        System.out.println(cartesianProduct(arr5,0,arr5.length).toString());
        int[][] arr6 = {{1},{2},{3},{4},{5},{6}};
        System.out.println(cartesianProduct(arr6,0,arr6.length).toString());
    }

    private static List<List<Integer>> cartesianProduct(int[][] arr,int curr_row,int length){
        List<List<Integer>> res = new ArrayList<List<Integer>>();
        if(curr_row == length) return res;

        List<List<Integer>> subproblem_result = cartesianProduct(arr,curr_row + 1,length);
        int size = subproblem_result.size();

        for(int i=0;i<arr[curr_row].length;++i){            
            if(size > 0){
                for(int j=0;j<size;++j){
                   List<Integer> current_combs = new ArrayList<>();
                   current_combs.add(arr[curr_row][i]);
                   current_combs.addAll(subproblem_result.get(j));
                   res.add(current_combs);
                }  
            }else{
                List<Integer> current_combs = new ArrayList<>();
                current_combs.add(arr[curr_row][i]);
                res.add(current_combs);
            }              
        }        

        return res;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
[[1, 1, 4], [1, 1, 5], [1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 5], [2, 1, 4], [2, 1, 5], [2, 2, 4], [2, 2, 5], [3, 1, 4], [3, 1, 5], [3, 2, 4], [3, 2, 5]]
[[1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 5], [1, 2, 6], [1, 3, 4], [1, 3, 5], [1, 3, 6]]
[]
[[1, 2]]
[[99, 2000], [101, 2000]]
[[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]]
```

**Explanation:**

- We can adopt either a top-bottom approach(like your code tries to do) or bottom-up approach, but let's go with bottom-up approach as you will understand it better.
- Let's take `{{1,2,3}, {1,2}, {4,5}}` as an example.
- We recursively call the `cartesianProduct()` till the deepest level, meaning till the last row. If the call exceeds it, we return an empty list.
- At the deepest level, we will be at `{4,5}` in our code. We add each element to the list by creating a new list, adding the element and finally adding this list to the list collection. Hence, we return the list to the next top row as `[[4],[5]]`.
- Next top row is `{1,2}`. Here, we again iterate over it's elements and while doing so, we add that element to each list inside returned list collection from our successive row.
  So, we add `1` to `[4]`, `1` to `[5]`, `2` to `[4]` and `2` to `[5]`. So, now our new returned collection would look like `[[1,4],[1,5],[2,4],[2,5]]`.
- Next top row is `{1,2,3}`. We do the same as above. So, we add `1` to each list in `[[1,4],[1,5],[2,4],[2,5]]` and same goes for `2` and `3`.
- Hence, our final list would look like `[[1, 1, 4], [1, 1, 5], [1, 2, 4], [1, 2, 5], [2, 1, 4], [2, 1, 5], [2, 2, 4], [2, 2, 5], [3, 1, 4], [3, 1, 5], [3, 2, 4], [3, 2, 5]]`.
- In the end, we just return the list as usual and print it using the toString() method.
- Note that if you use the top-bottom approach, you would still arrive at the correct answer, but the thing is order of combinations obtained would be different than you expected.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same question while working on a PHP project and found this topic which gave me the right input. Here is my quite short solution (in PHP) which doen't need any recursive function:

```
    $startlist = [ [1] , [2, 3] , [4, 5, 6]];

    $cartesian = [ [] ];    // Start with one empty element in the cartesian product result array
    foreach($startlist as $subarray){       // iterate over the startlist
        $newcartesian = [];                 // temporary helper
        foreach($subarray as $element){     // Iterate over all elements of the subarrays
            foreach($cartesian as $cartesiansubarray){      // iterate over each element in the cartesian product the we already have
                $cartesiansubarray[] = $element;            // add the element to each of these and
                $newcartesian[] = $cartesiansubarray;       // add them to the temporary helper
            }
        }
        $cartesian = $newcartesian;     // replace the cartesian product by the helper
    }

    echo json_encode($cartesian);       // json_encode() is just used to have a shorter printout
```

The output is as expected:

[[1,2,4],[7,2,4],[1,3,4],[7,3,4],[1,2,5],[7,2,5],[1,3,5],[7,3,5],[1,2,6],[7,2,6],[1,3,6],[7,3,6]]